# Redirecting old links to 1 url

Tags: django

I am trying to redirect all links from an old url pattern eg /portfolio/abc to /products/

The individual pages are not the same, so I just want any link starting with /portfolio/ to redirect to /products/

I have installed the Redirect app in the admin interface, so can easily redirect /portfolio/ to /products/ but not anything starting with /portfolio/ - is there syntax that I am not aware of that can do this? Or, do I need to do it in urls.py?

Comment: something like /portfolio/567 need to be redirected to /products/ or to /products/567 ?

Comment: the former: redirecting /portfolio/567 (or anything) to /products/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should go into your main `urls.py` file and should be first entry so that this url pattern is applied first:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/portfolio/[^$]*$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/product/')),
)
```

The regex pattern `r'^/portfolio/[^$]*$'` means that any URL starting with `/portfolio/` and there can be anything after that till end.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about RedirectView, nice!

Comment: Awesome, this worked (though I had to take out the / before portfolio). Nice and easy, thanks